# Ошибка подк видео(youtube) в приложении

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

Fragment

```
public class video_1 extends Fragment implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyA3lY117wtsfzrP8Yr-mPPHv9fIKjIud7Y";
    static private final String VIDEO = "LCn0edNbA7Q";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_1, null);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) v.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        YouTubePlayer player = null;
        player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
    }
    /*@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }*/

}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView // пробовал изменить на непомогло youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dip" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
      at com.whitestar.klip1.video_1.onCreateView(video_1.java:28)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
      at com.whitestar.klip1.video_1.onCreateView(video_1.java:28) 
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
      at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
      at com.whitestar.klip1.video_1.onCreateView(video_1.java:28) 
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В логах у вас написано:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.

т.е. вам надо или не фрагмент использовать, а активити, коя расширяет `YouTubeBaseActivity` или (не факт что сработает) поместить ваш фрагмент в такую активити

Comment: скажите в фрагменете видео не запустить(только в активити)?

Comment: @Андрей, я не знаю, ни разу не пробовал что-то такое делать. и даже впервые слышу о таких классах) Что в доках пишут и что вам мешает попробовать предложенные в ответе варианты? Это всяко быстрее, чем если я начну собирать проект чтобы это проверить)

Comment: мне очень нужно в фрагменте, сколько нужно заплатить вам что бы вы попробовали? сколько всего пере гуглил ничего не нашел только ето http://quabr.com/19664890/error-youtubeplayerview-xml

Comment: @Андрей, миллион долларов и я вам целиком приложение напишу)))))

Comment: Понял(( Спасибо)

Comment: @Андрей, вот, на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/87735/) пишут, что вроде есть отдельный фрагмент для этого `YouTubePlayerFragment`

Comment: спасибо))) сейчас перепишу код посмотрим что получится